# kaptKotlin gradle task fails on JDK 11

Tags: gradle, kotlin, java-11, kapt

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':module:kaptKotlin'.

  > Could not find tools.jar in system classpath, which is required for kapt to work

Comment: It's(tools.jar) not there since Java9. You might want to check with `kapt` for why was it even in use for and if they've looked to migrate?

Comment: This is a bug, please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27188 for updates.